# Simulate clicks on options

Tags: javascript

For example, if you click `<div id="click-object-2"></div>` the option will switch to *Earth*, after that to *Please choose*, and finally back to *Earth* again.

I made a gif to show what I'd like to accomplish:

[image]

Anyone know of a Javascript that can do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simulate clicks on options</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
div
{
width:30px;
height:30px;
margin:4px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#click-object-1{background-color:#F00;}
#click-object-2{background-color:#0F0;}
#click-object-3{background-color:#00F;}
#click-object-4{background-color:#FF0;}
</style>


<body>


<form action="">

  <fieldset>

    <ul style="list-style:none;">
      <li>
        <select id="select_items_first" name="SelectItemsFirst">
          <option value="choose">Please choose</option>
          <option id="fireaway" value="xjakgd">Fire</option>
          <option id="groundearth" value="yuygas">Earth</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li>
        <select id="select_items_second" name="SelectItemsSecond">
          <option value="choosemore">Please choose</option>
          <option id="watermelon" value="piowqe">Water</option>
          <option id="catchwind" value="mnbvzi">Wind</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </fieldset>

</form>

<div id="click-object-1"></div>
<div id="click-object-2"></div>

<br />

<div id="click-object-3"></div>
<div id="click-object-4"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand.... do you want simulate the click or do you want to record that action and replay it later?

Comment: You could go hardcore and use webgl :p

Comment: I'm just curious as to why you want it to switch to Earth, back to Choose and then back to Earth again. Why not just leave it at Earth the first time?

Comment: Thanks MeLight :)  @Felix Kling, I'd like to simulate the clicks.  Abe Petrillo, webgl - that would be fun ;)  Chris Pickett, it has to act like a refresh, if it only switches to Earth ones, my other script won't notice the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work :

Simulate clicks on options

```
<style type="text/css">
div
{
width:30px;
height:30px;
margin:4px;
cursor:pointer;
}

#click-object-1{background-color:#F00;}
#click-object-2{background-color:#0F0;}
#click-object-3{background-color:#00F;}
#click-object-4{background-color:#FF0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function grabClick(selid , optionid){
var arr = new Array();
arr['empty'] = "0";
arr['fireaway'] = 1;
arr['groundearth'] = 2;
arr['watermelon'] = 1;
arr['catchwind'] = 2;
changeTo(selid, arr[optionid]);
setTimeout(function(){changeTo(selid, "0")}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){changeTo(selid, arr[optionid])}, 2000);
}
function changeTo(sd, od){
var sel = document.getElementById(sd);
sel.options[od].selected = true;
}
</script>

<body>


<form action="">

  <fieldset>

    <ul style="list-style:none;">
      <li>
        <select id="select_items_first" name="SelectItemsFirst">
          <option id="empty" value="choose">Please choose</option>
          <option id="fireaway" value="xjakgd">Fire</option>
          <option id="groundearth" value="yuygas">Earth</option>
        </select>
      </li>
      <li>
        <select id="select_items_second" name="SelectItemsSecond">
          <option id="empty" value="choosemore">Please choose</option>
          <option id="watermelon" value="piowqe">Water</option>
          <option id="catchwind" value="mnbvzi">Wind</option>
        </select>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </fieldset>

</form>

<div id="click-object-1" onclick='grabClick("select_items_first","fireaway");'></div>
<div id="click-object-2" onclick='grabClick("select_items_first","groundearth");'></div>

<br />

<div id="click-object-3" onclick='grabClick("select_items_second","watermelon");'></div>
<div id="click-object-4" onclick='grabClick("select_items_second","catchwind");'></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It has to work for all `<div>'s` you click on, so if you click on `<div id="click-object-1"></div>` the option switches to _Fire_ --> _Please choose_ --> _Fire_. If you click on `<div id="click-object-2"></div>` the option switches to _Earth_ --> _Please choose_ --> _Earth_. If you click on `<div id="click-object-3"></div>` the option switches to _Water_ --> _Please choose_ --> _Water_. If you click on `<div id="click-object-4"></div>` the option switches to _Wind_ --> _Please choose_ --> _Wind_.

Comment: Thanks @mooglife It works in Firefox, but in ie6,7,8 I get the following error: `'options[...]' is null or not an object`

Comment: settimeout has some problem with IE...instead of directly calling the function...a closure calls it now...works fine in IE8, Chrome, FF.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is `Element.click();` method.
Like in this **example** code:

```
document.querySelector("#click-object-2").addEventListener( "click", function() {
    document.querySelector("#groundearth").click();
});
```

For choosing options you will need chained `setTimeout` to set `select.options[index].selected = true;`, but, hopefully, you can figure out how to do that by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function clickSelectNum(value) {
       document.getElementById("select_items_first").value = value;
       setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("select_items_first").value = "choose"}, 1000);
   }
</script>

<!-- and in the div onclick event you put the function call -->
<div id="click-object-2" onclick="clickSelectNum('earth')"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks MeLight. See the comment I gave to @mooglife

Answer (score 0):

Bind divClicked to your clickable div.

```
function divClicked()
{
   var timer = setTimeout(selectOption("groundEarth"), 1000);
   var timer2 = setTimeout(selectOption(), 2000);
   var timer3 = setTimeout(selectOption("groundEarth"), 3000);
}

function selectOption(optionId)
{
   if(optionId == null || optionId == '')
   {
      select.options[0].selected = 'selected';
   }
   else
   {
     $("#"+optionId).click();
   }
}
```

EDIT: Need JQuery for this to work, otherwise use document.getElementById

Comment: Thanks Andrew. However I can't use jQuery in this case. Also, see the comment I gave to @mooglife

Comment: So, couldn't you modify the "divClicked" function to allow passing an html element, check the ID and click specific options accordingly?